# Магический метод __hash__ в Python

Tags: python

Столкнулся с магическим методом **hash** в ооп в python. В инете и в документации мало примеров этого метода в ооп. Он возвращает число, id объекта. Но зачем он вообще нужен? Если для сравнения, то почему не использовать всем знакомые __ eq __, __ lt __, __ ne __ и т.д.?

```
def __hash__(self):
    return hash(Point.__repr__(self))
```

Скажите, что в этом случае возвращает **hash**?

P.S. Point - класс, в котором прописан метод repr и как раз этот hash.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__hash__

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Даже в Википедии [написано достаточно](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A5%D0%B5%D1%88-%D1%84%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F). По сути `hash` нужен для быстрого сравнения объектов. Это нужно например для словарей, именно за счёт хэша доступ по ключу в словарях так быстро работает. Полное сравнение объектов может работать долго, поэтому сначала сравниваются хэши объектов и только при их совпадении производится полное сравнение через `eq`. В идеале хэш должен быть с одной стороны небольшой по размеру, а с другой стороны разный для разных объектов. Это не всегда возможно и оправданно, поэтому в реальности хэш это некий компромисс и коллизии всё же бывают, но их немного, поэтому поиск по ключу в словаре и проверка наличия элемента в `set` работает моментально (за время порядка `O(1)`).

Детали реализации хэша в `Python` можно посмотреть в [документации по Python](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__hash__) (спасибо dIm0n за ссылку).